# Filter list of scala case classes by list with the class?

Tags: scala

I have the following `case class` in Scala:

```
case class Profile(userId: String, items: Map[String, Seq[Item]], subParts: Seq[SubPartAndCount], usedItems: Map[String, Long])
```

The `SubPartandCount` looks like this:

```
case class SubPartAndCount(subPart: String, subCount: Int)
```

So I want to filter a list of `Profile`s by the value of `subPart` within the `SubPartAndCount` case classes that are in the `subPart`s list.  I have been trying to figure this out with no success!  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `.filter(_.subParts.contains(_.subPart == "target_string"))`

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.exists(A => Boolean)` nested in a `.filter(B => Boolean)`:

```
profileList.filter(_.subParts.exists(_.subPart == "Part A"))
```

Here is an example:

```
type Item = String

case class Profile(userId: String, items: Map[String, Seq[Item]], subParts: Seq[SubPartAndCount], usedItems: Map[String, Long])

case class SubPartAndCount(subPart: String, subCount: Int)

val subPartA = SubPartAndCount("Part A", 100)
val subPartB = SubPartAndCount("Part B", 200)

val exampleItems = Map("Hello" -> Seq("World", "Galaxy", "Universe"))
val exampleUsedItems = Map("Hello" -> 1L, "Goodbye" -> 2L)

val profileList = Seq(
  Profile("good", exampleItems, Seq(subPartA, subPartB), exampleUsedItems),
  Profile("bad", exampleItems, Seq(subPartB, subPartB), exampleUsedItems),
  Profile("good", exampleItems, Seq(subPartB, subPartA), exampleUsedItems)
)

profileList.filter(_.subParts.exists(_.subPart == "Part A"))
```

[Try it out!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MarkusA380/HiDAshJESuCYOK0PEKGSVQ/2)

This statement evaluates to a `Seq` of the two "good" `Profile`s.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is strictly worse than @jwvh's comment because for most types of `Seq` it'll need to go through the entire sequence finding all items satisfying the condition, instead of stopping when the first one is found.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov Nowhere in his question it is stated that he wants only the first element found.

Comment: You can replace filter() with exists(). It returns when it finds the first match.